# Display Records if X is TRUE regards of Other Values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having some logic problems.

I have a table with a number of columns (`Name, Address etc`) and three called `recNewsLetter, recAGM and recPhoneCall` each a `Yes/No` populated by a `checkbox`.

I have another form with three checkboxes `Receive Newsletter, Receive AGM Info & To Phone`. I am looking to make a query where I can select one of the checkboxes in the form and it will display all records where that checkbox is true, regardless of the others.

For example, I want to see all the records where recNewsletter is true regardless of whether the others are true or not. Same if `recAGM` is true; I want to see all those records regardless of the status of `recNewsLetter` or `recPhonecall`.

My query is only displaying the records where the exact combinations exist. For instance, if recNewsletter is true (ie it's checkbox on the form is ticked), it will display only those records where it is true and the others are false. If both `recNewsletter` & `recAGM` are true then it will only display records where they are both true and the other (`recPhoneCall`) is false.

As you've probably guessed, my SQL is a basically a 'WHEN recNewsLetter AND recAGM AND recPhoneCall'. I'm after something that, for example, will show all records for newsletters regardless of the values of AGM or phonecall.

This is code:

```
SELECT tblOrganisations.ID, tblOrganisations.OrgName
FROM tblOrganisations
WHERE (((tblOrganisations.recNewsLetter) = 
[Forms]![frmPrintOrgLabels].[ReceiveNewsletter])) And 
(((tblOrganisations.recAGM) = [Forms]![frmPrintOrgLabels].[ReceiveAGMInfo])) And 
(((tblOrganisations.recPhoneCall)=[Forms]![frmPrintOrgLabels].[ToPhone]));
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

R

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't just modifying the sql to apply ONLY the criteria you want? eg SELECT ... WHERE recAGM=True.  If you want mutually exclusive results, do you have the 3 check boxes as part of a group, so as the group changes (ie, user clicks a checkbox), code behind modifies the WHERE condition for the query?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your description, you need something like

```
WHERE (

(tblOrganisations.recNewsLetter and [Forms]![frmPrintOrgLabels].[ReceiveNewsletter])

OR
(tblOrganisations.recAGM and [Forms]![frmPrintOrgLabels].[ReceiveAGMInfo])

OR 
(tblOrganisations.recPhoneCall and [Forms]![frmPrintOrgLabels].[ToPhone])

)
```